# iOS core-bluetooth Dynamic Scan Response data

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluegiga

Using a BLE113 I have been successfully using `kCBAdvDataLocalName`, in the scan response, to contain dynamically changing data from a sensor. This is then picked up nicely in an iOS App. iOS interprets the data associated with 
`kCBAdvDataLocalName` as a string which has its limitations. I need to send more data and cannot afford the space lost in encoding to ASCII.

Does anyone have recommendations for the sending of Raw data in Scan Responses?

Comment: Base64 encoding?

Comment: Don't mind as long as I can extract the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You can send out this data as an advertising packet (scan responses end up using more power, if I recall correctly).

An advertising packet, using a manufacturing ID of 0xff should allow you access to 31 bytes of data for you to use for whatever you want.

Check out the iBeacon examples here: https://github.com/sureshjoshi/ble113-firmware-examples

Similar concept.

If you're insistent on the local name, what is the encoding issue? If you're sending bytes of data, a string is just a set of bytes - so where are you losing data by encoding?

Comment: thanks for your thoughts: which part of the advdata array has spare capacity? I am looking for 10 bytes?

Comment: Have you read this article before? https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/02/10/bluetooth_advertisin-hGsf